# Analyzing large data file with MPI

Tags: mpi

I have a large file with regularly spaced data sets of equal size. I need to run some analysis on each, which is slow, so I'd like to split things up using MPI (I have access to a compute cluster).

Is there a good way to assign the data sets to different processes? Basically, I'm assuming I need to read through the file and each time a new set is encountered I hand that data to a new process. There are two catches though. There are as many as 10,000 data sets and I'm probably limited to 5-10 processes or so. I also want to write the analyzed data in the same order as the original data sets. Note that the different processes wouldn't have to communicate much - they would just need to synchronize so they wrote the analyzed data in the correct order.

If you're curious for more details, the data sets are configurations of a system (x,y coordinates of particles) and are ordered by time. The analyzed data should be the same time-ordered x,y coordinates but also include extra columns.

I'm new to MPI so apologies if my question has already been answered or if this is the wrong  forum. I searched for a while and couldn't find anything that helped.

The way I originally wrote my MPI script the separate processes all analyzed all the data sets. Obviously I want to divide up the analysis so each process only handles some of the data sets.

Comment: If your data sets have a size that is known beforehand then MPI I/O is very suitable. If not, then you have to seek through the file; you'd probably want a manager process and a bunch of workers.

Comment: Cool. I'll into MPI I/O. The size for each is 20002 lines so I know exactly where each begins and ends.

Comment: That makes it easy: MPI I/O is great when you can define portions of a file for each process. Those can be consecutive or even interleaved.